# I want to show user how many correct questions he answered. but it always show the ffirst alert with 3 correct anwsers

Tags: javascript, html

```js
 var first = prompt("It is a great time outside, isn't it? (yes / no)");
 first = "yes";
 if (first) {
  alert("I do agree with you, cool! Now let's see if you can complete next task");
 } else {
  alert("Sorry but you are wrong");
 }
 var a = +prompt("How many trunks does an elephant have?");
 a = 1;
 var b = +prompt("How many legs has a human body?");
 b = 2;
 var c = +prompt("How many planets are there in the Solar system?");
 c = 9;
 if (a,b,c) {
  alert("Perfect! You've answered 3 questions correct"); <!--i allways get this one, no matter if its all wrong... -->
 } else if (a !== 1 && b !== 2 && c !== 9) {
  alert("Sorry, you did not answer any question correct");
 } else if (a == 1 && b !== 2 && c !== 9 || a !== 1 && b == 2 && c !== 9 || a !== 1 && b !== 2 && c == 9) {
  alert("Bad! you gave only 1 correct answer");
 } else if (a == 1 && b == 2 && c !== 9 || a !== 1 && b == 2 && c == 9 || a == 1 && b !== 2 && c == 9) {
  alert("Not bad! You've answered 2 questions correct");
 }
```

So what could be the right code? Remember it must be beginner level, I am training basics. Thank you in advance

Answer (score 0):

I think this is a simple bug, namely your first conditional is not doing what you think it does.

```
   if(a == 1 && b == 2 && c == 9)
```

is what your first condition should look like.

Also, in the lines above that, you should not set a, b, and c to those values.

```
    var a = +prompt("How many trunks does an elephant have?");
    a = 1;
    var b = +prompt("How many legs has a human body?");
    b = 2;
    var c = +prompt("How many planets are there in the Solar system?");
    c = 9;
```

Should be

```
    var a = +prompt("How many trunks does an elephant have?");
    var b = +prompt("How many legs has a human body?");
    var c = +prompt("How many planets are there in the Solar system?");
```

Otherwise no matter what the prompt returns, you overwrite the value.

Answer (score 0):

You are not testing the answers correctly you should read the user answer in one statement and then use it test in an other

```
 var a = +prompt("How many trunks does an elephant have?");//reading the user input
 if(a==1)//testing the if user input is equals to the correct answer
 {...}
```

```js
var first = prompt("It is a great time outside, isn't it? (yes / no)");
 
 if (first=="yes") {
  alert("I do agree with you, cool! Now let's see if you can complete next task");
 } else {
  alert("Sorry but you are wrong");
 }
 var a = prompt("How many trunks does an elephant have?");
 var b = prompt("How many legs has a human body?");
 var c = prompt("How many planets are there in the Solar system?");
  var correctanswerscount = 0;

     if (a==1)
  correctanswerscount++;
    if (b==2)
  correctanswerscount++;
    if (c==9)
  correctanswerscount++;
  
 if(correctanswerscount == 3) {
  alert ("Perfect! You've answered 3 questions correct");
 } else if (correctanswerscount == 0) {
  alert("Sorry, you did not answer any question correct");
 } else if (correctanswerscount == 1) {
  alert("Bad! you gave only 1 correct answer");
 } else if (correctanswerscount == 2) {
  alert("Not bad! You've answered 2 questions correct");
 }
```

Comment: Thanks a lot... very simple, i mean understandable for < beginners like me. once again big big thanks.

Answer (score 0):

After collecting answer from the user you are immediately setting the answer back to the correct answer: (Comment out that second line for all three prompts)

```
 var a = +prompt("How many trunks does an elephant have?");
 //a = 1;
```

Next your initial comparison just checks to see if there are values, not that they are correct

```
if (a,b,c) {
```

change to:

```
if (a===1 && b===2 && c===9) {
```

so you check each against the correct answer. The '===' operator checks equality AND variable type.

Complete code:

```
var first = prompt("It is a great time outside, isn't it? (yes / no)");
//first = "yes";

if (first.toLowerCase().startsWith("y")) {
    alert("I do agree with you, cool! Now let's see if you can complete next task");
} else {
    alert("Sorry but you are wrong");
}

var a = +prompt("How many trunks does an elephant have?");
//a = 1;
var b = +prompt("How many legs has a human body?");
//b = 2;
var c = +prompt("How many planets are there in the Solar system?");
//c = 9;

if (a===1 && b===2 && c===9) {
    alert("Perfect! You've answered 3 questions correct"); 
} else if (a !== 1 && b !== 2 && c !== 9) {
    alert("Sorry, you did not answer any question correct");
} else if (a == 1 && b !== 2 && c !== 9 || a !== 1 && b == 2 && c !== 9 || a !== 1 && b !== 2 && c == 9) {
    alert("Bad! you gave only 1 correct answer");
} else if (a == 1 && b == 2 && c !== 9 || a !== 1 && b == 2 && c == 9 || a == 1 && b !== 2 && c == 9) {
    alert("Not bad! You've answered 2 questions correct");
}
```

Comment: Interesting, the most similar to mine, but there is also a little problem, maybe you didn't notice, no matter what i answer in the first question about weather, i get the first alert... even if it is wrong and should alert Sorry bla bla bla... Anyway thank you

Comment: You were explicitly setting the first variable to "yes" no matter what the user entered.  Then the comparison was lookinig for a boolean when it should be comparing strings.  See my edited answer.